# Dynamic horizontal menu overlays content when hidden

Tags: jquery, css, muse

I have a client who built a website using an Adobe Muse template. They asked me to create a form to use on their page. Now they have an issue where the dynamic horizontal menu overlays the form/content below it, even when the submenu is hidden, so the inputs under the submenu footprint cannot be selected/changed.

When the main menu is hovered, the submenu is shown-
[image]

but when the submenu is hidden, the footprint of that element is still there
[image]
So any inputs in the blue cannot be selected/changed. If they scroll up, so that the elements are below the blue area, then they can be selected/changed.

CSS is my weak point, so I am not sure what I am looking for to change to condense the submenu footprint when hidden. Using chrome developer tools I found if I uncheck `z-index: 192` or `position: fixed`

[image]
then the issue goes away, but the main menu also disappears.

I need help knowing what properties I need to change. The live site is located at http://utahdancefilmfestival.org/festival.html#submissions

Not knowing the Adobe Muse products, is it possible that this menu/css is generated by jQuery, and that is where I need to be looking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I noticed is that the overlaying box is not really a submenu footprint. It's actually always there, even when the nav menu hasn't been hovered.

[image]

It seems like it has an excessively tall height. So I adjusted the height...

```
#u11447 { height: 100px; }
```

... and got this:

[image]

With that height adjustment the mouse is able to access everything on the page.

Comment: Brilliant!! Thank you for your keen eye!

Answer (score 0):

I'v recently been experimenting with Muse, specifically the Muse CC Responsive pre-release app. Make sure to pay attention to your layer arrangement. Muse makes use of layers just like working in Photoshop and Illustrator. The proper arrangement will save you a lot of frustration. Also, become familiar with how master pages work. For instance, When you create a header or footer in the master page it automatically populates to the rest of your site map. You cannot edit the header/footer area outside of the master page as well.

Hope I was able to help.